# how to edit column in database via fetching unique ID/table id along with data CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

when you register a patient he can have a lot of records (separated data table) under a unique ID.

for example I register now and I have the unique `ID` of `patient1`. If I create a new record for `patient1` it will be under by his unique `ID`.

My problem is I can fetch it's data, but I can't edit it by fetching `tbl_id` (from separated table).

Here's my code -

Model :

```php
function get_record($tbl_id) 
  {
     $query = $this->db->select('tbl_id, record_date, diagnosis');
     $this->db->from('patient_medical_info');
     if (!is_null($tbl_id)) $this->db->where('tbl_id', $tbl_id);
     $this->db->order_by('tbl_id', 'desc');        
     $result = $query->get()->row();
     return $result;
  }

public function save_edit_patient_medical($medical,$patient_id){
     $this->db->where('patient_id',$patient_id);
     $this->db->update('patient_medical',$medical);
  }
```

controller :

```php
$medical =  array(
             'tbl_id'          => $this->input->post('tbl_id',true),
             'patient_id'      => $this->input->post('patient_id',true),
             'record_date'     => $this->input->post('record_date',true),
             'diagnosis'       => $this->input->post('diagnosis',true),

            );

$this->patient_model->save_edit_patient_medical($medical,$tbl_id);
```

view

```html
<input type="text" name="record_date" value="<?php echo @$record->record_date;?>"> 
<input type="text" name="diagnosis" value="<?php echo @$record->diagnosis;?>">
```

Comment: and where does this `$pmi_id` comes from?

Comment: `$tbl_id` needs to be defined, like `$tbl_id=$this->input->post('tbl_id',true)`

Comment: Both inputs in your view is called "patient_id". You do not set record_date nor diagnosis anywhere on the update.

Comment: @HastaDhana sorry it was supposed to be tbl_id

Comment: @KobusMyburgh sorry my mistake. code is now fixed. record date is created via controllers : 
$create_date = date('Y-m-d');
'record_date'       =>$create_date,

it shouldn't be changed because my it's only "update/change" infos

Comment: @Vickel        upon using define, All codes are running smoothly but apparently nothing changes in database.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Vickel's answer :  `$tbl_id needs to be defined, like $tbl_id=$this->input->post('tbl_id',true)`